# Get coordinates of a programatically created imageview Android

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

So i am creating my views programatically like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_devices; i++) {

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp = new LinearLayout.
                LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(vp);

        try {
            Class res = R.drawable.class;
            Field field = res.getField(device_types.get(i));
            int resId = field.getInt(null);
            imageView.setImageResource(resId);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MyTag", "Failure to get drawable id.", e);
        }

        LinearLayout link_devices = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.link_devices);
        link_devices.addView(imageView);
}
```

And i am trying to get the coordinates of the imageview:

I have tried the following methods, but am getting no where

```
       imageView.getDrawable().getBounds().centerX() /centreY
       imageView.getX() / getY
       imageView.getLocationInWindow(); / onScreen();
```

Could someone please explain to me how to get the cooridinates of the image which is a drawable so i can draw a box around it or draw lines between two images (that is the planned functionality)

Comment: what did you end up doing? currently having the same issue.

Comment: @DanCat retrieving getTop() and getLeft() works for your x,y coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

```
int top = imageView.getTop();
int left = imageView.getLeft();
```

From there you have the top-left point coordinates.

Comment: This means that the view is at coordinates (0, 0) of its parent. Use the same technique if you nested the parent inside another view.

Comment: it isnt nested and it isnt in the top left